# Log4j and appender, is this log4j definition correct?

Tags: java, log4j

If I have log4j setting below.

And I log against:

org.berlin2.Mycode.info("something");

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,ConsoleAppender,LifeSimAppender
log4j.logger.org.berlin2=DEBUG,ConsoleAppender,LifeSimAppender
```

... Is the log4j definition correct, what will happen?  LifeSimAppender writes to a file.  ConsoleAppender is the console appender.  I only want to write to the file once.

What is the difference between the definition above and:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,ConsoleAppender,LifeSimAppender
log4j.logger.org.berlin2=DEBUG
```

In the first scenario, do I need to explicitly define the 'appenders'.

Comment: I can't see what you're trying to achieve. BTW, it seems you will have duplicate logs since you have the same appenders on 2 loggers. You may add `additivity` property to the org.berlin2 logger to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

I tried it with the first one "DEBUG,ConsoleAppender,LifeSimAppender" and I got the following erros:

```
og4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "ConsoleAppender".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.LifeSimAppender
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "LifeSimAppender".
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.ali.play.Test).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I tried it with the second one then I got the warning below:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.ali.play.Test).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I recommend looking at the log4j website for setting up the property file. Here is the [link](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) for you.

Comment: Yea those appenders aren't there.  I didn't give the whole log4j file.  Assume ConsolerAppender is the apache log4j console appender.  And LifeSimAppender is some other appender.  In my first code post, I don't think I need that second line, that is what I was trying to ask.